# IronPython: Most efficient way to convert a nested python list to a .NET array

Tags: python, .net, ironpython

I would like to know a typical, efficient, "pythonic" method for converting a nested list to a typed .NET Array. Currently I am doing it in a naive way without comprehensions as I can't figure out how to do it without indices:

```
from System import Array

lstNest = [[j for j in xrange(2)] for i in xrange(10)]
intArr = Array.CreateInstance(int,10,2)
for i in xrange(len(lstNest)):
    for j in xrange(len(lstNest[i])):
        intArr[i,j] = lstNest[i][j]
```

Comment: Your solution works?  How is it inefficient?

Comment: [This VB code snippet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3) in the docs shows setting array values using a nested for loop with indices.